# Is it possible to nest methods in Vue.js in order to group related methods?

Tags: javascript, methods, vue.js, namespaces, nested

I'd like to group some of my Vue.js methods together in a sort of "submethod" class, but I only seem to be able to have single level methods.

For example, if I wanted to have a set of methods dealing purely with button actions:

```
new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: { },

    methods: {

        buttonHandlers: {

            handler1: function() {
                dosomething;
            },

            handler2: function() {
                dosomething;
            }

        }

    }

});
```

I would expect to be able to then use something like:

```
<button v-on:click="buttonHandlers.handler1">Click Me</button>
```

but nothing happens.

I *have* tried forcing the function to run by adding brackets:

```
<button v-on:click="buttonHandlers.handler1()">Click Me</button>
```

but I receive this console error:

***Uncaught TypeError: scope.buttonHandlers.handler1 is not a function***

I've setup a small https://jsfiddle.net/ozx9oc4c/ to demonstrate what I mean.

If anyone knows of a way to logically group functions under parent methods in Vue.js, rather than pages and pages of single level methods with no real structure, I'd be grateful for your knowledge.

Comment: If you have pages and pages of methods, chances are you should be building smaller components. Your button should be its own component, most likely.

Comment: @ceejayoz Totally agreed - In this instance, I'm actually working a multi-step form and a lot of the methods are to do with validation, step progression, field manipulation etc, so I'd like to keep them within a single Vue instance if possible, but grouped into logical classes; this button example I've given is the quickest relevant sample I could think of.

Comment: no go, https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1470#issuecomment-386930594

Comment: Weird how now in 2020 Vue team is trying to group related options (methods/computeds) together (composition API) but something that lets you group related methods together is not accepted

Answer (score 12):

The closest I've got to doing this, is to declare the parent as a function, and return an object with a set of methods.

Example:

```
new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {},

  methods: {

    buttonHandlers: function() {
      var self = this; // so you can access the Vue instance below.

      return {

        handler1: function() {
          dosomething;
          self.doSomething();
        },

        handler2: function() {
          dosomething;
        },

      },

    }

  }

});
```

And you can call the methods like this:

```
<button @click="buttonHandlers().handler1()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I have been using this answer, for a while, but I now recently found out that you can just use modern syntax to **avoid the** `var self = this`. You can write a sub-function like `handler1(){}` now, which keeps the `this` context inside that function scope. *And* generally you don't want to use `var` any more and use `const` or `let` instead to avoid weird variable scoping.

Comment: I cannot edit my message anymore, but I meant `handler1: () => {}`: an **arrow function** captures **this**

Comment: I'm not able to make it work on Google Chrome 91. My grouping arrow func is something like  `grouping_func: () => ({ method1:  () => {}, ... })` but inside method1 this points to the grouping_func object.

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a *very* simple technique: define your nested methods in the `created` hook:

```
created() {
  this.on = {
    test: () => {console.log(this)}
  }
  this.on.test();
}
```

NOTE: Two things, A) in this case you *must* use arrow function(s) and B) if this feels "hacky" to you, perhaps because of the cluttering of the `created` lifecycle hook, you can always delegate to a method, let's say `this.namespaceMethods()`, e.g.:

```
created() {
  this.namespaceMethods();
  // call namespaced methods
  this.foo.bar();
  this.foobar.baz();
  // etc.
},
methods: {
  this.namespaceMethods() {
    this.foo = {
      bar: () => {console.log("foobar")}
    },
    this.foobar = {
      baz: () => {console.log("foobarbaz")}
    }
  },
  // etc
}
```

Comment: i honestly don't like it, I used an arrow function returning the object inside the methods() but still felt weird so i bumped it to the computed() as an object and i'm semi comfortable. still feels kinda hacky. idk, I like the function returning the object better I guess. I wasn't saying its ugly or wrong, just felt hacky, to me, personally. i meant no offense :)

Answer (score -1):

if i had that problem, i would use a click handler() to delegate request to other methods.
eg:

```
new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: { },

    methods: {

        handler1: function() {
             console.log("handler 1 called");
        },

        handler2: function() {
            console.log("handler 2 called");
        },

        buttonHandler:function(callback){
            callback();
        }


    }

});
```

and use html as

```
<button v-on:click="buttonHandler(handler1)">Click Me</button>

<button v-on:click="buttonHandler(handler2)">Click Me</button>
```

The code is only for demo. 
In real life i will be passing a number or string argument in template and using switch case to determine handler.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution still leaves me in the same position where I end up with 3 functions in the top level of my _methods_ object - there's no logical organisation in a hierarchy.

Comment: hmm, can you elaborate your use case. and also how many methods and logical partitions you are talking about? oh do add info in your post, not in comments here

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue (the need of a namespace) while writing a Vue mixin. This answer doesn't directly address your case, but it could give a clue.

This is how I defined the mixin.

```
export default {
   created () {
    // How to call the "nested" method
    this.dummy('init')

    // Pass arguments
    this.dummy('greet', {'name': 'John'})
   },

   // Namespaced methods
   methods: {
     dummy (name, conf) {
       // you can access reactive data via `that` reference,
       // from inside your functions
       const that = this

       return {
         'init': function (conf) {
            console.log('dummy plugin init OK')
         },
         'greet': function (conf) {
            console.log('hello, ' + conf['name'])
         }
       }[name](conf)
     }
   }
 }
```

PS: for an official solution, Evan You [said no](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1470#issuecomment-386930594).