# How put more objects or clases inside the "methods" object in vue csp?

Tags: vue.js

I have a chrome extension that uses Vue csp

I instantiate it like this:

```
class MyMethods {
  testMe(){}
  anotherFunction(){}
}

const methods = new MyMethods();

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => appData,
  methods
});
```

and it works, I can use `testMe()` and `anotherFunction()` in my template (html file).

```
<button v-on:click="testMe()">testMe()</button>
<button v-on:click="anotherFunction()">anotherFunction()</button>
```

But I want to segment it into more classes like, `MyMethodsX`, `MyMethodsY`, so I can expand them when I needed.

But I do not find any way to make Vue to understand that I have not just an object but an object of objects. That is I want to group functions that work with the same thing like:

```
<button v-on:click="tests.testMe()">testMe()</button>
<button v-on:click="handling.anotherFunction()">anotherFunction()</button>
```

I have tried:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => appData,
  methods : {
      methodsX: new MyMethods()
  }
});
```

or

```
class MyWrapperClass() {
  methodsX = new MyMethods()
}
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => appData,
  methods : new MyWrapperClass()
});
```

but I can not call `testMe()` it always says "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined".

Is there a way to do this so I can put new namespaces/classes/objects in a Vue app Methods key?

Edit:

My end goal is to have something like this:

```
<div class="tests" v-if="testing">
    <button :click="testing.test1()>Testing Uno</button>
    <button :click="testing.test2()>Testing Dos</button>
</div>
<div class="handling" v-if="handling">
    <button :click="handling.func1()>Handling Uno</button>
    <button :click="handling.func2()>Handling Dos</button>
</div>
```

where each category is a class with their own methods (and probably tests :) )

Comment: How are you calling `testMe()` in the first example?  Whenever I try to call it I get an error.

Comment: @zero298 I have updated my question :)

Comment: according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956988/10153945) you can do it but I couldn't make it work

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your use case, but I don't think you want to composite your functions in a `class`.  If I am understanding you correctly, you want to be able to create a collection of functions that other things can use as though they were methods.  In that case, I think you should take a mixin approach.

Instead of creating a `class` that has the collection of methods, just create a simple `Object` with all the functions and then spread them onto the object that wants to have them:

```js
const appData = {
  foo: "bar"
};

const MyMethods = {
  me() {
    return "me";
  }
};

const YourMethods = {
  you() {
    return "you";
  }
};

const methods = {
  ...MyMethods,
  ...YourMethods
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => appData,
  methods
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">{{me()}} | {{you()}}</div>
```

Comment: was going to write the same

Comment: Hi @zero298, thank you for your answer. I have updated my question. I think I wasn't clear about my use case.